# Update model fields based on POST data before save with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework and want to augment the posted data before saving it to my model as is normally achieved using the model's clean method as in this example from the django docs:

```
class Article(models.Model):
...
def clean(self):
    # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
    if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
        raise ValidationError(_('Draft entries may not have a publication date.'))
    # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
    if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
        self.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
```

Unfortunately a django-rest-framework Serializer does not call a model's clean method as with a standard django Form so how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/):

> The one difference that you do need to note is that the .clean() method will not be called as part of serializer validation, as it would be if using a ModelForm. Use the serializer .validate() method to perform a final validation step on incoming data where required.
>
> There may be some cases where you really do need to keep validation logic in the model .clean() method, and cannot instead separate it into the serializer .validate(). You can do so by explicitly instantiating a model instance in the .validate() method.

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    instance = ExampleModel(**attrs)
    instance.clean()
    return attrs
```